# Eclipse formatter changes in Neon

Tags: java, eclipse, code-formatting

Me and my colleagues are facing an issue introduced by an Eclipse update. I used Eclipse Kepler for years and formatted our entire repository of Java code with it but now colleagues start to use the newest Neon version.

We have used the same formatter settings over years and on Neon it produces a different result:

[image]

Our formatter settings are shared using an XML file. The line wrappings are now different and we couldn't make it work as expected. Seems like Neon wants to keep instantiations in one line.

[image]

For me, reformatting 20k LOC and screwing up the file history is not a good option. Did anyone approach the same issue and found a solution?

Comment: The formatter was completely rewritten in Eclipse Mars. [This blog](https://eclipse-n-mati.blogspot.co.uk/2015/06/eclipse-mars-how-to-switch-back-to.html) claims to have a way to use the old formatter - I have not tried this.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks a lot for the link. So there is no way of using the new formatter with the old line wrapping style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if that's an option for you, but I found it useful being able to use the old formatter implementation (the one used by Eclipse Luna and before) to avoid reformatting of existing code bases. Here's a blog post that introduces an Eclipse plugin that lets you choose the formatter implementation to use in the settings:
http://eclipse-n-mati.blogspot.de/2015/06/eclipse-mars-how-to-switch-back-to.html